# create & delete polgon on map then unable to redraw polygon

Tags: google-maps, draw, polygon

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_hidePolyline.html

This is the url, when we create a polygon (then polygon become there with black boundary) and delete that by clicking on delete button then i am not able to draw polygon again with black boundary

Answer (score 1):

Function `deleteMarkers()` calls `clearMarkers()` which set map for polyline to null. So function `deleteMarkers()` could be changed to:

```
function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    poly.setPath([]);

    poly.setMap(map); 

    markers = new Array();
    pathroute = new Array();
}
```

so map is set back for polyline.

Comment: Thanks Anto, This was the block of code which really solved my issue, Thanks a lot

Comment: fixed the example. Thank you.